# How to override to remove/comment a line in customer_listing.xml in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2.2

I want **remove/comment** this line **`<filterSearch name="fulltext"/>`**  in **customer_listing.xml** located in **vendor/magento/module-customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml**

I want to make changes in Override module at **app/code/Custom/Customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml**
 I just placed following code, but didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="add">
                <url path="*/*/new"/>
                <class>primary</class>
                <label translate="true">Add New Customer</label>
            </button>
        </buttons>
        <spinner>customer_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>customer_listing.customer_listing_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="customer_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>
        <aclResource>Magento_Customer::manage</aclResource>
        <dataProvider class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider" name="customer_listing_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
        <!-- <filterSearch name="fulltext"/> -->  // made changes here
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions">
            <action name="delete">
                <settings>
                    <confirm>
                        <message translate="true">Are you sure to delete selected customers?</message>
                        <title translate="true">Delete items</title>
                    </confirm>
                    <url path="customer/index/massDelete"/>
                    <type>delete</type>
                    <label translate="true">Delete</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
            <action name="subscribe">
                <settings>
                    <url path="customer/index/massSubscribe"/>
                    <type>subscribe</type>
                    <label translate="true">Subscribe to Newsletter</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
            <action name="unsubscribe">
                <settings>
                    <confirm>
                        <message translate="true">Are you sure to unsubscribe selected customers from newsletter?</message>
                        <title translate="true">Unsubscribe from Newsletter</title>
                    </confirm>
                    <url path="customer/index/massUnsubscribe"/>
                    <type>unsubscribe</type>
                    <label translate="true">Unsubscribe from Newsletter</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
            <action name="assign_to_group">
                <settings>
                    <type>assign_to_group</type>
                    <label translate="true">Assign a Customer Group</label>
                    <actions class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\MassAction\Group\Options"/>
                </settings>
            </action>
            <action name="edit">
                <settings>
                    <callback>
                        <target>editSelected</target>
                        <provider>customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns_editor</provider>
                    </callback>
                    <type>edit</type>
                    <label translate="true">Edit</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="customer/index/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns.ids</param>
            </editorConfig>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids" sortOrder="10">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="entity_id" sortOrder="20">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="name" sortOrder="30">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Name</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="email" sortOrder="40">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Email</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="group_id" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="50">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Group</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_telephone" sortOrder="60">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Phone</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_postcode" sortOrder="70">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">ZIP</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_country_id" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="80">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Country</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_region" sortOrder="90">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">State/Province</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date" sortOrder="100">
            <settings>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Customer Since</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="website_id" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Websites" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="110">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Web Site</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="confirmation" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Confirmation" sortOrder="130">
            <settings>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Confirmed email</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="created_in" sortOrder="140">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Account Created in</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_full" sortOrder="150">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Billing Address</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="shipping_full" sortOrder="160">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Shipping Address</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="dob" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date" sortOrder="170">
            <settings>
                <timezone>false</timezone>
                <dateFormat>MMM d, y</dateFormat>
                <skipTimeZoneConversion>true</skipTimeZoneConversion>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Date of Birth</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="taxvat" sortOrder="180">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Tax VAT Number</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="gender" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="190">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Gender</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_street" sortOrder="200">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Street Address</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_city" sortOrder="210">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">City</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_fax" sortOrder="220">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Fax</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_vat_id" sortOrder="230">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">VAT Number</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_company" sortOrder="240">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Company</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_firstname" sortOrder="250">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Billing Firstname</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_lastname" sortOrder="260">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Billing Lastname</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="lock_expires" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\AccountLock" sortOrder="270">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Account Lock</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Actions">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: you should redeploy static content. But why do you want to edit core files directly? that's not the recommended way

Comment: i don't want to do it in core files, in future if you migrate to new version we need to do it again.  Basically i want to hide search box on every page such as sales_order_listing it's working for customer page but not sales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

Comment: that what i need

Comment: Where you found this method? Any document from magento2? I want to read more about this.