# Remove Search By Keyword Box in admin grid

Tags: magento2, admin, search, customer-grid

I have to remove this Search By Keyword box in customer grid. I overrided the `customer_listing.xml` but I dont know the syntax to disable it.

```
<filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
```

Do anyone have idea how to disable this

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the fulltext search using the following code

```
<filterSearch name="fulltext">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</filterSearch>
```

Just put it your ui_component XML file to make it done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentDisabled`

Exactly been asked here: [How to override to remove/comment a line in customer_listing.xml in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262043/how-to-override-to-remove-comment-a-line-in-customer-listing-xml-in-magento-2)

If the only purpose is to hide it, you can use CSS, it's much easier.